# How to use the return type of one function as an argument type of another function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the shape

```js
const shape = {
  foo: () => 'hi', 
  bar: (arg) => typeof arg === 'string'
// arg should be string because foo returns a string
}
```

how do I link the `foo`'s return type to the `arg`'s input type?

I've tried several versions of conditional types similar to

```js
type Cond<T> = T extends { foo: () => infer A }
  ? { foo: () => A; bar: (arg: A) => bool }
  : never
```

but I failed.
Any ideas?

Comment: `Cond<typeof shape>` returns the correct type as far as I can see.

Comment: Unfortunately `arg` does not correct its type, it falls back to `any` for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

If we forget about the self-referential object for a second, the simplest way to approach this is using the `ReturnType` utility type provided by TS:

```
const foo = () => "hi";
const bar = (arg: ReturnType<typeof foo>) => typeof arg === "string";
const shape = { foo, bar };
```

We can narrow this by defining a shape interface such that the two methods are linked via the object itself:

```
interface Shape {
  foo: () => string;
  bar: (arg: ReturnType<Shape["foo"]>) => boolean;
}

const shape: Shape = {
  foo: () => "hi",
  bar: (arg) => typeof arg === "string"
}
```

And we can write utility/factory function which does this dynamically with generics for any two provided methods:

```
const asMyShape = <
  F extends () => void, 
  B extends (arg: ReturnType<F>) => void
>(foo: F, bar: B) => ({ foo, bar });

const shape = asMyShape(() => "hi", (arg) => typeof arg === "string");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be solvable using generics:

```js
class Shape<T> {

  public bar = (arg: T) => typeof arg === 'string';

  constructor(
    public foo: () => T,
  ) {}
}

const someImplementation = new Shape(
  () => 'test'
);

const someOtherImplementation = new Shape(
  () => 43
);

someImplementation.bar(someImplementation.foo());
someOtherImplementation.bar(someOtherImplementation.foo());
```

[Working example can be found here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAWYAOBTAPAFQHzQN4Ch9pokBXAIxAEthpywAnaAXmgApGBzALmgwEoWOAC4BPVAHsAZtC4tmrAOQRhDKgDtOigNyFiwCepUNSwYRIZsixEhWq0pEibzaDmODABprg3AF98APwDI2FoCAkAWxQASUikEBRo9WEwYSpDFmh1FAB3OERUK2JXIWhFYRQVRXx+XWDDFXColAB5YXgUBjiEpJQUtIz1LJz8hGQUYvY3HAAWAGZa+ojonsTk1PTDADp6SxXY+PX+zaHtxwlXOvwD9s7uo76BrfVdxjZbjq61p9Odi6u2iAA)

The compiler will complain when you try to pass an incorrect type to the `bar` function:

```js
someOtherImplementation.bar('string'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```